# Power Apps dropdown items from gallery

Tags: dropdown, gallery, powerapps, powerapps-modeldriven, powerapps-collection

In my Power Apps screen, there is a dropdown control and a gallery control. A gallery control which is connected to a SharePoint list.
Then I have bind the gallery item to a dropdown control using this code
**Distinct(ShowColumns(Gallery6.AllItems,"Status"),Status.Value)**

Problem is to get only particular dropdown item from a gallery.

But, my requirement is I need bind the particular value from gallery control like
I need to to show only the "Completed" value in the dropdown control. So I tried the below code but I was getting the dropdown values as Yes or no

**Distinct(ShowColumns(Gallery6.AllItems,"Status"),Status.Value="Completed")**

Please Help me out to get only particular dropdown item from a gallery.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Uw3k.jpg)